# What is a germ of a presheaf?

Tags: homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory, affine-schemes, presheaves

I’m trying to figure out the notions of germs and stalks of a presheaf. I had understand the definition is there an example though? Also I was thinking why there was a reason to construct these two notions? Is there anything they help us proof or have another use? I found them while studying of the construction of affine schemes do they help us about something about the functoriality of Spectrum maybe?